# Как удалить все саб пути из списка?

Tags: c++

У меня не много опыта в С++ (и возможно, то что мне нужно можно сделать какими то стандартными методами, но я не нашел).

У меня есть вот такой список путей

```
C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder
```

Мне нужно их очистить таким образом, чтоб полусилось вот так

```
C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder
```

Эти пути были удалены

```
C:\\Sessions\\Calibrations\\2020_04_30_18_02 
C:\\Sessions\\Calibrations
```

Так как этот путь `C:\\Sessions\\Calibrations` суб путь от этого `C:\\Sessions\\Calibrations\\2020_04_30_18_02` и собственно этот путь `C:\\Sessions\\Calibrations\\2020_04_30_18_02` это суб путь от `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test`.

У этого пути `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test` нет суб пути поэтому он остается в списке.

Как я это сделал

```
/*static*/ std::vector<std::string> Utils::remove_sub_folders(std::vector<std::string> folderPaths_in)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        std::vector<std::string> executed_paths;
        std::vector<std::string> folder_paths = folderPaths_in;
        std::sort(folder_paths.begin(), folder_paths.end());

        for each (auto & path in folder_paths)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> path_split = Utils::split(path, "\\");

            for each (auto & compare_path in folder_paths)
            {
                bool is_have_alredy_processed = false;

                for each (auto & processed_path in executed_paths)
                {
                    if (compare_path == processed_path)
                    {
                        is_have_alredy_processed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!is_have_alredy_processed)
                {
                    std::vector<std::string> compare_path_split = Utils::split(compare_path, "\\");

                    int path_split_size = static_cast<int>(path_split.size());
                    int path_compare_size = static_cast<int>(compare_path_split.size());

                    if (path != compare_path && path_compare_size >= path_split_size)
                    {
                        int min_size = min(path_split_size, path_compare_size);

                        bool is_equal_begin = true;

                        for (int i = 0; i < min_size; i++)
                        {
                            std::string path_word = path_split[i];
                            std::string compare_word = compare_path_split[i];

                            if (path_word != compare_word)
                            {
                                is_equal_begin = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ((!is_equal_begin && path_split_size == path_compare_size))
                        {
                            result.push_back(path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            executed_paths.push_back(path);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

я не могу понять как правильно все это заставить работать, но результат, что у меня получается это

```
C:\Sessions\Calib
C:\Sessions\Calib\2020_04_30_18_02
C:\Sessions\Calib\2020_04_30_18_02\test
```

Вот так я вызываю этот метод

```
std::vector<std::string> all_dirs_by_path{
            "C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder",
        };
std::vector<std::string> final_dirs_by_path = Utils::remove_sub_folders(all_dirs_by_path);
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как-то все сложно. Зачем разбивать строки? `std::copy_if` и проверка, начинается ли какая-любо другая строка с этой строки + \ в качестве предиката. Еще `for each (auto & path in folder_paths)` является нестандартным синтаксисом.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `<filesystem>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге все решилось вот таким способом

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511019/5709159

```
using namespace fs = std::filesystem; // or use boost::filesystem here

static bool is_parent(const fs::path &parent, const fs::path &child) {
    auto parent_size = std::distance(parent.begin(), parent.end());
    auto child_size = std::distance(child.begin(), child.end());
    return child_size > parent_size && std::equal(parent.begin(), parent.end(), child.begin());
}

std::vector<fs::path> remove_sub_folders(std::vector<fs::path> paths) {
   std::sort(paths.begin(), paths.end());
   std::vector<fs::path> result;

   for(auto cur = paths.begin(); cur != paths.end(); ++cur) {
       auto next = std::next(cur);
       if (next == paths.end() || !is_parent(*cur, *next))
           result.push_back(*cur);
   }

   return result;
}
```